# Extracting list elements following a specific marker

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of data (called `MyList`), and I need to extract every value that appears after a certain marker (in this case `1000000000`). Unfortunately the number of values in between the markers are not known in advance, which means that `Partition` can't be used. I can't extract each value manually as there are thousands of such entries.

```
MyList = {100000000, 241, 282, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 280, \
2, 0, 141675, 0, 52313, 0, 60293, 0, 146917, 100000000, 234, 267, 1, \
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 267, 0, 112814, 0, 605096, \
100000000, 202, 239, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 236, 3, \
0, 137451, 0, 14687, 0, 602723, 0, 146917, 100000000, 247, 304, 1, 2, \
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 294, 10, 0, 103246, 0, 52313, 0, \
603875, 0, 146917, 100000000, 245, 292, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, \
10, 1, 11, 289, 3, 0, 185242, 0, 14687, 0, 606101, 0, 146917, \
100000000, 215, 266, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 265, 1, \
0, 109229, 0, 146917, 0, 605375, 0, 146917, 100000000, 243, 294, 1, \
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 292, 2, 0, 284599, 0, 14687, 0, \
605777, 0, 146917, 100000000, 246, 285, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, \
10, 1, 11, 283, 2, 0, 249383, 0, 14687, 0, 596362, 0, 14687, \
100000000, 249, 295, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 292, 3, \
0, 13235, 0, 146917, 0, 602667, 0, 146917, 100000000, 259, 300, 1, 2, \
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 1, 11, 299, 1, 0, 148557, 0, 14687, 0, \
60267, 0, 14687}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `SequenceCases[MyList, {100000000, x_} :> x]`?

Comment: Can marker repeat one another ie. `...,100000000,100000000,...` ?

Answer (score 11):

```
Pick[Rest@MyList, Most@MyList, 100000000]

(* {241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259} *)
```

Comment: Serious showstopper.

Comment: @Syed Thanks.  I need one of those!!

Answer (score 8):

```
Extract[MyList, Position[MyList, 100000000] + 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

**Using `SequenceSplit`:**

```
SequenceSplit[MyList, {100000000}] // Map[First]
```

**Using `Split`:**

```
Split[MyList, #1 == 100000000 &] /. {{_} -> Nothing} // Map@Last
```

> {241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `SequencePosition` and `Take`:

```
Map[Times @@ Take[list, #] &@*List@*Last]@SequencePosition[list, {100000000, _}]

(*{241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}*)
```

Or using `SequencePosition` and `Part`:

```
Part[list, #[[2]]] & /@ SequencePosition[list, {100000000, _}]

(*{241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}*)
```

**Edit**: As @Syed suggest, a simpler way:

```
list[[Last /@ SequencePosition[list, {100000000, _}]]]
```

Comment: Simpler: `MyList[[Last /@ SequencePosition[MyList, {100000000, _}]]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[Partition[MyList, 2, 1], {100000000, _}][[All, 2]]


(*{241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Marker:

```
m = 100000000;
```

Using `ReplaceRepeated` with `x` as placeholder

```
Cases[{x, a_} :> a] @
 ReplaceRepeated[list, {h___, m, a_, t___} :> {h, {x, a}, t}]
```

> {241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}

Using `SubsetPosition` (new in 12.1)

```
Extract[SubsetPosition[list, {m}] + 1] @ list
```

> {241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}

Using `SequencePosition` (a variant of E. Chan-López answer)

```
Extract[Cases[{a_, _} :> {a + 1}] @ SequencePosition[list, {m}]] @ list
```

> {241, 234, 202, 247, 245, 215, 243, 246, 249, 259}